# Prove this proposition by cases

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

When i try to prove this proposition by cases

$$x^2 + w^2 + y^2 = z^2$$

Where $x$, $y$, $w$ are positive integers .. $z$ is even if and only if $x$, $y$ and $w$ are even

I represent even as $2i$
And odd as $2i + 1$

When i try the case that 2 of them are odd and the another is even

I get $(4i^2 + 4i + 4i^2 + 4i + 2)$

And that is an even .. am i wrong ? Or the proposition is wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! I prettified your math using MathJax -- click 'edit' to see how it's done.

Comment: When $z$ is even, $z^2$ is a multiple of $4.$

Comment: Can you explain ?

Comment: $(4i^2 + 4i + 4i^2 + 4i + 2)$ is not a multiple of $4$

Comment: Since $x$ and $y$ are not necessarily the same, and $z$ is not necessarily one less than $x$, the numbers should have been $2i+1,2j+1,2k$.

Comment: Thank you alot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposition is correct, and you are correct that $4i^2 + 4i + 4i^2 + 4i + 2 = 8i^2 + 8i + 2$ is an even number, but that sum is equal to $z^2$, not $z$.

There is no $z$ that squares to this quantity, even or odd -- something we can see by trying to factor it and failing. And we know such a $z$ isn't even, anyway, since (like Will Jagy's comment says) the square of an even number must be a multiple of $4$.

(Proof: $(2i)^2 = 4i^2$).

Comment: Then $z^2$ must be multiplied by 4 to say that $z$ is even ?

Comment: Yep -- in order for $z$ to be even, your expression for $z^2$ must be a multiple of $4$. $4i^2$ isn't the only such multiple, just the simplest one. ($4i^2 + 4i$ would be another).

Comment: If $z^2$ is 4$i^2$ then z is even ?

Comment: @MohamedRamzyHelmy: Yes.

Comment: Thank you alot for helping me

Comment: @MohamedRamzyHelmy: Sure. Keep in mind Andre Nicolas's comment too -- I didn't notice it, but using $i$ for all the numbers means that they're all the same, which I don't think you intended.